# Error in caret-svm - "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"

Tags: svm, r-caret

experts. I am a beginner to R. I am trying to use caret-SVM to make classification. The kernel is svmPoly.
First, I used the  default parameters to train the model with leave-one-out cross-validation
The code is :

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV",
                     classProbs = T,
                     savePredictions = T,
                     repeats = 1)
modelFit <- train(group~.,data=table_svm,method="svmPoly",
                  preProc = c("center","scale"),
                  trControl = ctrl)
```

The best accuracy is 80%. And the final values used for the model were degree = 1, scale = 0.1 and C = 1 .

Second,  I tried to tune the parameters.
The code is:

```
grid_svmpoly=expand.grid(degree=c(1:11),scale=seq(0,5,length.out=25),C=10^c(0:4)) 
modelFit_tune <- train(group~.,data=table_svm,method="svmPoly",
                  preProc = c("center","scale"),
                  tuneGrid=grid_svmpoly,
                  trControl = ctrl)
```

I got an error message: Error in { : 
  task 264 failed - "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"

I checked the data and found no NA.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some NA inside the data-set. I am not new to this but not much expert. To ensure there is no NA inside first convert data-set into matrix format using:

```
x <- data.matrix(dataframe)
```

then use which() function which very handy in this case:

```
which(is.na(x)==T)
```

I hope this will help you finding the answer. The values will be in row wise order.

Let me know if this resolve your query.

Comment: Thanks, Nandi. I used your code to look for NAs and got "integer(0)" .

Comment: I try to reproduce the problem using a small dataset with the same parameters and it worked without any difficulty. I think you may also want to try this. So, install "mlbench" and there is one dataset Ionosphere. Use Ionosphere data and run that above code. It will work. Please let me know if you have any difficulty with that.

Comment: Thank you, Nandi. I still can not figure out the cause to this problem. However, i got no error after replacing `tuneGrid=grid_svmpoly` with `tuneLength=9`. The accuracy increased to 85%.